# keycloak remove default roles that are added automatically

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

I am using keycloak 12.0.4 and I want new local or synced federated users to not have default roles. when we create the realm from the JSON file... it still always add "uma_authentication" and "offline_access" why?
Even if I put an empty list and if I add a list with other roles.
it adds the role and this two roles also.

Is there a way to remove those? without the need to update the realm?

Answer (score 3):

Those are default roles, you can remove them by navigating to keycloak admin - Roles - Default Roles.

These comes as default for any client application integration being setup.

Comment: There seems to be a role called "default-xxx-role" (where xxx is your realm name), which gets automatically added to every new user. Its not listed in realm roles though

Comment: I think you mean `default-roles-{realmName}` :)